# Iitaka dimension of a $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier Prime divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, divisors, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a normal projective variety and $D$ a prime divisor such that $mD$ is Cartier for some integer $m>0$.
Suppose $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=0$ and $mD|_D\sim 0$.

My questions are the following:

Main Question 1. Is the Iitaka dimension $\kappa(X, D)=\kappa(X, mD)>0$?

To solve above, one may come up with the following question.

Question 2. Is $\mathcal{O}_{mD}(mD)\cong \mathcal{O}_{mD}$?

Question 3. Can we remove the assumption $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=0$ for the above questions?

Comment: If the question is too general, one may focus on the case when $X$ is a normal projective surface.

Comment: What about the case of $P^1 \times P^1$ and D is a fiber of either projection.

Comment: @aginensky In your example one has $\kappa(D)=1$ unless I'm mistaken

Comment: If you remove the assumption $H^1(X,\mathcal O_X)=0$, then there is a counter-example due to Demailly-Peternell-Schneider (Ex 1.7 in "Compact complex manifolds with nef tangent bundles"). There, $X$ is a projectivization of a rank 2 vector bundle $E$ over an elliptic curve (a non-trivial extension of two trivial line bundles) and $D$ will be the zero locus of the only section of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P(E)}(1)$.

Comment: @ Henri,  my bad,  I misread what is asked.

Comment: @Henri Thank you very much for the example! $D|_D\sim 0$ since $\Lambda^2 E$ is trivial.